# How to I get currMethodName in Netbeans Code Template area?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am writing netbeans code template to achieve below case

My current code:

```
Logger.log("${classVar editable=false currClassName default=getClass()}. ${classVar editable=false currMethodName default=getClass().getEnclosingMethod()} -> Error:",
                    level3);
```

if I type lsqle inside some method like below

```
public class classA{
  private void deleteCode(uCodeC code) {
    lsqle+TAB
  }
}
```

Expected Result:

```
public class classA{
  private void deleteCode(uCodeC code) {
    Logger.log("classA.deleteCode -> Error:",level3);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the answer to my earlier question. ${methodName currMethodName editable="false"} is what I was looking for hence the code should be as below.

Logger.log("${classVar editable=false currClassName default=getClass()}.${methodName currMethodName editable="false"} -> Error:",
                    level3);

Comment: How to get line number in netbeans